# app.callback won't update component in dash

Tags: python, plotly-dash

[This](https://github.com/harryob2/blood_lactate_dash) is a link to a github repo with the full code, I will only include here the pieces of code that are relevant. If you would like to test the web app, I have included a csv file in the repo which you should use when uploading a file.

The app.callback won't update the dash_split_pane and I'm not sure why. Any help would be appreciated.

```
app.layout = dash_split_pane.DashSplitPane(
    children=[pane1, pane2],
    id="splitter",
    split="vertical",
    size=500
    )

@app.callback(Output('splitter', 'children'), 
              Input('upload-data', 'contents'),
              State('upload-data', 'filename'),
              State('table-container_3', 'data'),
              prevent_initial_call=True) #need to include this or else the rest of the code doesn't work
def update_plot(HR_df, filename, GUI_df):
    if filename is not None:
        global pane1
        children = [pane1, [parse_contents_plot(HR_df, filename, GUI_df)]] # this function creates the figures inside a html.div
        
        return children
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to make a simple change to how I structured children. See below.

```
@app.callback(Output('splitter', 'children'), # change layout to output-plot
              Input('upload-data', 'contents'),
              State('upload-data', 'filename'),
              State('table-container_3', 'data'), prevent_initial_call=True)
def update_plot(HR_df, filename, GUI_df):
    if filename is not None:
        global pane1
        pane2 = parse_contents_plot(HR_df, filename, GUI_df)
        children = [pane1, pane2]
        
        return children
```